# C++ No instance of overloaded function getline matches argument list

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm writing a program which needs to read input from cin into a string. When I tried using the regular getline(cin, str) it endlessly prompted for input and never moved on the the next line of code. So I looked in my textbook and it said I could pass a cstring and size of the string to getline in the form of cin.getline(str, SIZE). However, when I do that I get the error "no instance of overloaded function getline matches the argument list.

I searched around, but all I found was people saying to use the getline(cin,str) form which led to the infinite input prompt, or the suggestion that there might be two different getline functions with different parameters in the classes I'm including, and that I need to tell the IDE to use the correct one(I'm not sure how to do that).

This is what I include at the beginning of my file:

```
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "Bank.h"   //my own class

using namespace std;
```

And this is the relevant section of code:

```
        const int SIZE = 30; //holds size of cName array
        char* cName[SIZE];   //holds account name as a cstring   (I originally used a string object in the getline(cin, strObj) format, so that wasn't the issue)
        double balance;      //holds account balance

        cout << endl << "Enter an account number: ";
           cin >> num;       //(This prompt works correctly)
        cout << endl << "Enter a name for the account: ";
           cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()); //clears cin's buffer so getline() does not get skipped   (This also works correctly)
           cin.getline(cName, SIZE); //name can be no more than 30 characters long   (The error shows at the period between cin and getline)
```

I'm using Visual Studio C++ 2012, if that's relevant

Comment: You can avoid size issues by just going `string cName; getline(cin, cName);`  . If you have problems with that then post the code that is causing problems.

Comment: @Matt McNabb Originally I had `string name; and getline(cin, name);` and the rest of the code was identical minus the char array and size constant. But that caused the program to infinitely prompt for input, never ending no matter how many characters I typed or how many times I pressed enter. Any ideas what might have caused that?

Comment: There are no loops in this code so it cannot "infinitely" prompt for input.

Answer (score 2):

This is the offending line:

```
char* cName[SIZE];
```

What you really need here is:

```
char cName[SIZE];
```

Then, you should be able to use:

```
cin.getline(cName, SIZE);
```

Comment: No standard functions behave like that; it should be `SIZE` , not `SIZE-1`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I was under the wrong impression all along. Thanks for helping me understand the functions better. I've removed the incorrect statements from my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the error, however now I'm stuck with the same infinite input prompt that I had with getline(cin, stringObject), whiich defeats the whole purpose of using cin(cstring, size) as a workaround. Any advice there?

Comment: @user3502796 If you can post more of your code, it will be useful in figuring out what's going on. Without additional code, it's hard to see why you are getting into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

This error message from visual studio is quite misleading. Actually for me I was trying to call a non const member function from const member function.

```
class someClass {
public:
    void LogError ( char *ptr ) {
        ptr = "Some garbage";
    }
    void someFunction ( char *ptr ) const { 
        LogError ( ptr );
    }
};
int main ()
{
    someClass obj;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually compiler gives a pertinent message (a bit misleading because argument is the implicit argument which is the object used to call the method).

Answer (score 0):

Related to the answer of R Sahu the compiler gives a clue that an argument does not match. It is true that is a bit misleading because the argument is not in the paranthesys but outside the explicit argument list. If you add a const LogError function then ambiguity is resolved and the compiler will find what to call depending if LogError is called from read write function or read only function.
Try the following code which does not give the error and makes situation more clear.

```
    #include <iostream>

    class someClass {
    public:
        void LogError(char* ptr) {
            std::cout << "LogError: before arg=" << ptr << "\n";
            ptr[0] = 0;
            std::cout << "LogError: after arg=" << ptr << "\n";
        }
        void LogError(char* ptr) const {
            std::cout << "const LogError: arg=" << ptr << "\n";
        }
        void ROFunction(char* ptr) const {
            LogError(ptr);
        }
        void RWFunction(char* ptr) {
            LogError(ptr);
        }
    };
    int main()
    {
        char s[] = "test";
        someClass obj;
        obj.ROFunction(s);
        obj.RWFunction(s);
        obj.ROFunction(s);
        return 0;
    }
```

With the output:

```
const LogError: arg=test
LogError: before arg=test
LogError: after arg=
const LogError: arg=
```

You can think that "this" pointer is used as an implicit argument and in one case is "const someClass *" pointer and in the other is "someClass *" (without const).